# Drawing a custom button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am drawing a custom button:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,44,70);
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Order" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I am tapping on the button the back ground color is not changing. Do I need to use different images for normal and selected state? What is the trick here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use different images for different states:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:someUIImageRef forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:someOtherUIImageRef forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
because you're using a custom button, you need to describe every single state manually or they will look like the normal state.